# 40k Event Log Errors an hour Unknown Username or bad password

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, windows-event-log

I am getting about 200k of these an hour:

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:    Security ID:        SYSTEM  Account Name:       TGSERVER$   Account
Domain:     WORKGROUP   Logon ID:       0x3e7

Logon Type:         4

Account For Which Logon Failed:     Security ID:        NULL SID    Account
Name:       administrator   Account Domain:     TGSERVER

Failure Information:    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad
password.   Status:         0xc000006d  Sub Status:     0xc0000064

Process Information:    Caller Process ID:  0x334   Caller Process
Name:   C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe

Network Information:    Workstation Name:   TGSERVER    Source Network
Address:    -   Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:    Logon Process:      Advapi
    Authentication Package: Negotiate   Transited Services: -   Package
Name (NTLM only):   -   Key Length:     0

This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on
the computer where access was attempted.

The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which
requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the
Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or
Services.exe.

The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested.
The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on
the system requested the logon.

The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request
originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left
blank in some cases.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information
about this specific logon request.
    - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
    - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
    - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.
```

On my server...  I changed my adminstrative username to something else and since then I've been inidated with these messages.

I found on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787567(v=WS.10).aspx that the 4 means "Batch logon type is used by batch servers, where processes may be executing on behalf of a user without their direct intervention." which really doesn't shed any light on it for me.

I checked the services and they are all logging in as local system or network service. Nothing for administrator.

Anyone have any idea how I tell where these are coming from? I would assume this is a program that is crapping out...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there any scheduled tasks on the system?

Comment: Wow you are awesome. I've spent 3 hours on this and never thought about the scheduler!!!  TY TY TY!!

Comment: Great!  When the system lets you, go ahead and put an answer on this question so that future searchers will be able to easily see it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Shane's instructions, I checked the Task Scheduler and lo and behold there was an event that said failed due to authentication errors. I changed the username and password and reran it and the log file showed no more entries.